# SQL Server Compiling and Calculating Data from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to find the hour of day in which a subscriber in my database opens the most emails.

I have a table with a bunch of subscriber IDs, I have another table with email opening records mapped to a table that stores sent emails which then maps to specific subscriber IDs.

So my basic desire is to get a table output with each row being a specific subscriber (subscriber ID) and the hour that they opened the most emails in. So I need to first go through each subscriber ID, then I guess create a temp table with each row being a different hour associated with the number of emails they opened in that hour. Then I need to do a select Max to get the max row from that temp table, then I need to place that into my output table, and repeat for the next subscriber.

All I care about is the hour of day. I don't care about month, or year or time. I just want to know what hour of day people mostly open emails.

I've been trying and trying, using CTEs and while loops but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the (minimized) structure:

Table: Subscribers

| subscriber_id | last_name | first_name |
|   9999999999  |   Smith   |   John     |

Table: SentEmail

| message_id | subscriber_id |
| 9028340    | 9999999999    |

Table: OpenEmails

| open_id | message_id | dtopened                  |
| 9923489 | 9028340    | '2011-11-22 15:53:02.157' |

My goal, an output table like this (last column is unnecessary) with each subscriber_id being unique in the list:

| subscriber_id | OpenHour | NumOpens |
| 999999999     | 10       |   32     |

Comment: Welcome to SO. The best way to proceed with this question is to create your Data Definition and what you have tried so far (DML) using SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Try join those tables, then group by subscriberID, DATEPART(HH,opendate) , then count on email id or something. If you need the query code, you need to share your schema and some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some assumptions since there wasn't a structure included.

Here is the structure I used.

```
CREATE TABLE Subscriber (
    Id int not null identity(1,1),
    SubscriberId varchar(50)
    )
CREATE TABLE EmailOpened (
    OpenDate DateTime,
    EmailId int
    )
CREATE TABLE Emails (
    EmailId int not null identity(1,1),
    SubscriberId varchar(50),
    EmailText varchar(max)
)
GO
```

Here is the query I ended up with.

```
WITH OpenedByHour AS (
    SELECT 
        SubscriberId,
        DATEPART(YEAR, OpenDate) AS OpenYear,
        DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, OpenDate) AS OpenDOY,
        DATEPART(HOUR, OpenDate) AS OpenHour,
        COUNT(1) AS OpenCount
    FROM Emails
    JOIN EmailOpened
        ON Emails.EmailId = EmailOpened.EmailId
    GROUP BY 
        SubscriberId,
        DATEPART(YEAR, OpenDate),
        DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, OpenDate),
        DATEPART(HOUR, OpenDate)
    ),
    MaxOpenedByHour AS (
    SELECT
        SubscriberId,
        OpenYear,
        OpenDOY,
        OpenHour,
        OpenCount,
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By SubscriberId
                Order By OpenCount Desc) AS MaxRow
    FROM OpenedByHour
    )
SELECT SubscriberId,
    OpenYear,
    OpenDOY,
    OpenHour,
    OpenCount
FROM MaxOpenedByHour
WHERE MaxRow = 1
```

Comment: This is returning a list of all subscriber ids and the count for each hour that they have in the database. So I'm getting multiple rows per subscriber

Comment: I made a change.  Try now.

Comment: This looks promising but I'm getting odd results like 0000000Jay AND
="00919322 as subscriber ids. the subscriber id's are stored as varchar's, is that causing the issue?

Comment: It works perfectly when I limit it to one id using a WHERE clause

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have some bad data in your subscriber id table?  Varchar shouldn't make a difference.  Actually if you look I assumed that.  A lot of times though you will get some bad data in columns like that.  You never notice it until you do a summary report like this.  Query your subscriber table for a subscriberid of  0000000Jay and see if it turns up.

Comment: Oh you're right, there are weird IDs like that in the "Emails" table but not in the main Subscribers table. Very odd! But I'll figure that out, Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Join the final query to your Subscribers table.  That will eliminate anything that isn't in the subscribers table.  Or of course get rid of the bad data :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to figure out how to tweak it with the correct columns and what not since the schema was not provided...

```
With    orderedHourly As
(
        Select  SubscriberID, 
                Convert(Date,OpenDateTime) OpenDate, 
                Hour(OpenDateTime) OpenHour, 
                Row_Number() Over (Partition By SubscriberID, Convert(Date,OpenDateTime) Order By Count(1) Desc) As HourPriority
        From    subscriber s
        Join    email e
                On  s.subscriberID = e.subscriberID
        Group   By SubscriberID, Convert(Date,OpenDateTime), Hour(OpenDateTime)
)
Select  SubScriberID, OpenDate, OpenHour
From    orderHourly
Where   HourPriority = 1
```

Comment: It looks like it worked but I'm getting more than one row per subscriber_id

Comment: This would give you one row per day. Did you want the hour with the most activity over an extended period of time?

Comment: It looks like you got an answer that works for you so no worries. Glad you got it figured out.